# Rapidxml and start tags

Tags: c++, xml, eclipse, rapidxml

I am having a few problems with rapidxml. When I compile my code no start tags  are included..any and all help will be greatly appreciated

```
    int main(){


    xml_document<> doc;
    //xml declaration
    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version","1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "utf-8"));
        doc.append_node(decl);
     // root node
        xml_node<>* root = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "root");
        root->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute(""));
                    doc.append_node(root);
                // child/sibling node
        xml_node<>* sibling0 = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "old");
        root->append_node(sibling0);
        xml_node<>* sibling = doc.allocate_node(node_element,"boy");
        root->append_node(sibling );
                 std::string xmlstring;
        print(back_inserter(xmlstring), doc);
        cout << xmlstring << endl;}
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the necessary #includes, and  missing `using namespace rapidxml;` your code compiles and runs fine for me.

xmlstring contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root ="">
    <old/>
    <boy/>
</root>
```

Because `old` and `boy` have no content, they use xml empty element tags, `<tagname/>`rather than start and end pairs like `<tagname></tagname>`